# how to create grouped x-editable dropdown in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap, x-editable

I have used x-editable table in my project. i need the dropdown should be grouped like below.

All 
  Celebrities
     -cricketer
     -actor
  Ordinary 
under celebrities , i have cricketer, actor etc., the sub categories of celebrities will get by remote api. but the three main groups should be get by local. when i add new subcategory to server under celebrity, it should come under celebrities.How to do this. can anyone please help me. 
**html**

```
 <span editable-select="user.category_id" e-name="category_id" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="c._id as c._id for c in categories">
              {{ showCategories(user) }}
             </span>
```

**controller**

```
    $scope.showCategories = function(user) {
        var categoryName;
        var selected = [];
        if (user.category_id) {
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.categories.length; j++) {
                if (user.category_id == $scope.categories[j]._id) {
                    categoryName = $scope.categories[j].name;

                }
            }
            selected = $filter('filter')($scope.categories, {
                value: categoryName
            });

            return categoryName;
        }
        return selected.length ? selected[0]._id : 'Not set';
    };
```

Comment: can u create a plunker or fiddle so that it will be easy to help

Comment: there is default jsfiddle of x-editable table http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/93/

Comment: this is a default one whats your problem create a fiddle for that

Comment: Here, i want the selectbox like this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6uL1QIdkltIHBh1TcrRa?p=preview) using xeditable table.here i have given local data.

Comment: how to show the subcategories here, like the above plunker shows. i will add subcategories to celebrity category only. in x-editable table

Comment: what is celebrarity here dont make complicated u wants to add in dropdown or what still its unclear the question

Comment: sorry, if i made complicated.i want to show the e-ng-options as grouped in selectbox.  i have the items like All ,Celebrities(-cricketer,-actor),Ordinary .   here the -cricketer and -actor are subcategories under celebrities. in the above plunker, ng-repeat is used.i need it with e-ng-options of x-editable table. so i hope it will get u know the problem. can you please help me on this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113889/discussion-between-gayathri-and-codelearner).

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/jNMKcHw9MjHz4rKoBYaV?p=preview